# magento redirect particular category and its subcategory to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

I have one category in magento shop called shop online. I want to redirect this category and its sub category to the home page using the htaceess.
Tried this in htaccess to redirect 
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop-online/$ http://www.domainname.com/index.php`

can anyone please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento, it's wrong to do redirects in .htaccess, but most newbies still solve the issue this way.... Your problem is that category urls in Magento usually have .html extension, so try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop-online.html$ http://www.domainname.com/index.php
```

The correct way is to create a url rewrite. In the admin, go to Catalog -> Url Rewrite Management. Create a custom URL Rewrite for your Shop Online category. If there's already a url rewrite for your category (there will be one when the category is first created), delete it.

[image: url rewrite screenshot]

Basically how url rewrites work is that Magento looks at the url and matches it to the Request Path in the above screenshot. If it matches, it sends a location header to the Target Path.

Comment: thanxxx for your help i already done using htaccess. i will also try the backend you told :)